# Spree generator not working when type 'rails g spree site'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator, spree

Hi i'm a newbie for developing rails application and i have interest
    in using 'spree' for my Ecommerce website.

I'm following this tutorial in spree from this site
    http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html

1. I made a fresh install as the tutorial above guided me. I made it to the part '5.1 Starting     up Spree' using rails 1.9.3 and mysql
   database.    Everything was fine until i notice the login bar wasn't
   appearing like the tutorial did.
2. I did some research which led me to this solution in 
      https://github.com/railsdog/deface/issues/12 
         what i understand from this article, it seems that the problem comes from a 'bug' from the defacement gem when using ruby 1.9.3 ,
   but the problem does not appear in 1.9.2   so i changed my ruby
   version into 1.9.2 to try it out.
3. After i installed ruby 1.9.2 i installed 'spree' gem I repeated the project (using mysql    database) from the 'getting started
   tutorial' to finish the tutorial.
4. now at part 4.4.2  where i type 'rake db:create'   terminal outputs this

   store$ rake db:create 
   store_test already exists 
   store_development already exists
5. When i try generate spree site by 'rails g spree:site' , terminal gives me this error

> ```
> store  rails g spree:site
>           create  config/spree.yml /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.70.2/lib/generators/spree/site/site_generator.rb:16:in
>     `block in config_spree_yml': undefined method `version' for
>     Spree:Module (NoMethodError)    from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:54:in
>     `call'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:54:in
>     `render'    from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in
>     `block (2 levels) in invoke!'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in
>     `open'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:63:in
>     `block in invoke!'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:114:in `call'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:114:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'    from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:61:in
>     `invoke!'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in
>     `action'    from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:26:in
>     `create_file'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spree_core-0.70.2/lib/generators/spree/site/site_generator.rb:15:in
>     `config_spree_yml'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in
>     `run'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in
>     `invoke_task'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in
>     `block in invoke_all'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in
>     `each'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in
>     `map'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in
>     `invoke_all'    from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/group.rb:226:in
>     `dispatch'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in
>     `start'     from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/generators.rb:168:in
>     `invoke'    from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/strong textrails/commands/generate.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'  from
>     /Usestrong textrs/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in
>     `require'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in
>     `block in require'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in
>     `block in load_dependency'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in
>     `new_constants_in'  from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in
>     `load_dependency'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in
>     `require'   from
>     /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in
>     `<top (required)>'  from script/rails:6:in `require'    from
>     script/rails:6:in `<main>'
> ```

1. I was pretty confuse because i didn't create a database before (but it is showing that it existed). And now i can't even generate
   spree site. I researched this problem for days and i haven't found a
   matching solution yet.  This is what my Gemfile looks like

   source 'http://rubygems.org'

   ```
   gem 'rails', '3.1.2'

   # Bundle edge Rails instead:
   # gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

   gem 'mysql2'


   # Gems used only for assets and not required
   # in production environments by default. group :assets do   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5.rc.2'     gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'  
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3' end

   gem 'jquery-rails'

   # To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
   # gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

   # Use unicorn as the web server
   # gem 'unicorn'

   # Deploy with Capistrano
   # gem 'capistrano'

   # To use debugger
   # gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

   group :test do   # Pretty printed test output   gem 'turn', '0.8.2',
   :require => false

   gem 'spree' , '0.70.2'

   end
   ```
2. I'd really appreciate if someone can give me some pointers or solutions to my problems. I'm quite lost right now, it'll sure make
   someone happy.   (tell me if u need more information about my ruby
   environment)

Comment: Is it necessary to run the 0.70 version?  You should be using the latest if possible.  The instructions you linked to above are for a slightly earlier version than latest (only delta is that rails needs to be 3.2.9 for latest).  You don't seem to be following those instructions anyway, so you may at least need to correct your link to the 0.70 getting started docs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you started with a fresh Rails application? Here's what I did (yesterday) using Ruby 1.9.2p290, Rails 3.1.1 on Fedora 16:

1. Make sure that ImageMagick in installed - the bootstrap script won't work without it.
2. Run rails new appname --database mysql
3. cd appname
4. Add gem, 'spree', '0.70.3' to Gemfile
5. Run bundle
6. Configure database.yml
7. Run rake db: create - ignore any database exists errors
8. Run rails generate spree:site - ignore any database exists errors
9. Run rake db:bootstrap

That should be it.

Answer (score 1):

Just realised - you've got "gem 'spree'..." inside the ":test" group. Not good. Don't muck about with the Gemfile - just add the spree gem at the end.

Answer (score 1):

As of today (December 2nd, 2012) the current version of spree which is compatible with ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.9 is spree -v '1.2.2"

http://spreecommerce.com/blog/2012/11

Version 1.3 is set to release in December 2012

I am no expert, but I think you need to change your gemfile to

```
gem 'spree', '1.2.2'
```